# Retrieve Map/Reduce Task ID within the M/R script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a process being executed in a Map/Reduce script which creates a bunch of quotes.

I would like to be able to add the Map/Reduce task ID to a field on the Quote/Estimate record.

The question therefore... is there a way to access the actual current task ID from within the M/R Script itself.

It would look something like: `MAPREDUCETASK_02686f177c0a7667707763070b7c7752500068061c10016f1c470041_dc257c953b420bea6b7`

Answer (score 1):

Even though Task ID is not directly accessible from the script context (as it was already mentioned by ehcanadian), it can be obtained through Scheduled Script Instance search triggered from within the map/reduce script.

Example:

```
const _getCurrentTaskId = () => {
        let scriptObj = runtime.getCurrentScript();
        let scriptId = scriptObj.id;
        let scriptDeploymentId = scriptObj.deploymentId;

        let mapReduceTaskSearch = search.create({
            type: search.Type.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT_INSTANCE,
            filters: [
                ['status', 'anyof', 'PROCESSING'],
                'AND',
                ['script.scriptid', 'is', scriptId],
                'AND',
                ['scriptdeployment.scriptid', 'is', scriptDeploymentId]
            ],
            columns: [
                'taskid'
            ]
        });

        let taskId;

        mapReduceTaskSearch.run().each(function(result) {
            taskId = result.getValue('taskid');
        });

        return taskId;
    }
```

Please note that if you have more SuiteCloud processors and running the same script deployment in parallel, this solution won't work (as it may return Task IDs of other currently running script deployments).

Answer (score 0):

For MR you can get (and set) script ID and deployment ID, and ID of each task you ran from map/shuffle/reduce stages.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a method to get the currently executing M/R's task ID from within the M/R itself, as it's not exposed via the context. However, you could store that value in a custom record to be retrieved within the executing M/R if you're executing the M/R via script. (Checking script ID and deployment ID.) It won't be failsafe if you're executing more than one M/R of the same script though.

Comment: Thanks for that, confirming what i suspected.

Comment: For now, I'm actually creating my own random ID, and storing that on the records I'm working with, so I can generate a "processing status" custom list, seems to be working well.